# php recursive function foreach result unexpected

Tags: php

This is a simple recursive example in foreach loop ubable to understand the result why am I getting this result? 
Answer will be appreciated.

```
function sub($i = 1){
   $level = array(1,2);
   if($i <= 2){
      foreach ($level as $count){
          echo "count => {$count} and i => {$i}<br/>";
          sub(++$i);
      }
   }
}

sub();
```

I am getting this result

```
count => 1 and i => 1
count => 1 and i => 2
count => 2 and i => 3
count => 2 and i => 2
```

I am expecting this result

```
count => 1 and i => 1
count => 1 and i => 2
```

Comment: ___Getting what result???___

Comment: I added my result.

Answer (score 0):

## This will be an infinite loop, until it is killed abruptly

**For reference**
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Explanation:

1. Function sub does not terminate based on a condition.

   variable $i is incremented but include the statement when to stop.

Comment: @PH.niskhkar so why I am getting the last result

count => 2 and i => 2

Answer (score 0):

## The value of `$i` has been changed

When you execute `sub(++$i)` you actually change the value of `$i` to be incremented with one. So when your function returns and the foreach loop goes to the second value of the array, the value of `$i` has changed, giving unexpected results.

Try doing `sub($i + 1)` instead. The output is now correct, but still different from your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for `$i <= 2` outside the loop.  So the test never happens when you are inside the loop. There are other problems as well but those are probably due to things you did to address that problem.